# html and body tags close before I tell them to PHP

Tags: php, html, tags

So I'm redesigning some tools at work to make a cohesive user experience and I have 2 files that I will include in all the rest. They are a header and a footer. They work independently but when I try to include them in the same file the footer does not show (I even tried putting them in one include file).

Here's the header:

```
<?php

function pageHeader($title){
    $html = "<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <link href='../../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css' rel='stylesheet'>
        <title>$title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='navbar navbar-fixed-top'>
            <div class='navbar-inner'>
                <div class='container-fluid'>
                    <a class='brand' href='/platform'>Platform Tools</a>
                    <div class='btn-group pull-right'>
                        <a class='btn dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' href='#'>
                            <i class='icon-user'></i>
                            Username
                            <span class='caret'/>
                        </a>
                        <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
                            <li>
                                <a href='#'>Profile</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class='divider'/>
                            <li>
                                <a href='#'>Sign Out</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class='nav-collapse'>
                        <ul class='nav'>
                            <li class='active'>
                                <a href='#'>
                                    <i class='icon-home icon-white'></i>
                                    APEX Home
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href='/platform/cms'>
                                    <i class='icon-home icon-white'></i>
                                    CMS Home
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href='/platform/outbound'>
                                    <i class='icon-home icon-white'></i>
                                    Outbound Home
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href='/platform/urs'>
                                    <i class='icon-home icon-white'></i>
                                    URS Home
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href='#bug'>
                                    <i class='con-fire icon-white'></i>
                                    Report a problem
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src='/bootstrap/js/jquery.js'/>
        <script src='/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-transition.js'/>
        <script src='/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-alert.js'/>
        <script src='/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-modal.js'/>
        <script src='/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js'/>
        <script src='/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js'/>
        <script src='/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-tab.js'/>
        <script src='/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js'/>
        <script src='/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-popover.js'/>
        <script src='/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-button.js'/>
        <script src='/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-collapse.js'/>
        <script src='/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-carousel.js'/>
        <script src='/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js'/>  ";

        return $html;
        }
?>
```

and Here's the Footer:

```
<?php
function pageFooter(){
    $html ="
    <nav class='footer'>
        <a href='#'>Apex</a>
        <a href='#'>Contest</a>
        <a href='#'>Outbound</a>
        <a href='#'>URS</a>
        <a href='#'>Third Party Tools</a>
        <a href='#'>Report a Problem</a>
        <a href='#'>Our SLA</a>
        <a href='#'>Contact</a>
    </nav>
    </body>
    </html> ";

    return $html;
    }
?>
```

When I include them in my FrontDoor.php file it looks like this (going to change to relative path):

```
<?php include('C:\xampp\htdocs\webapps\Redesign\Oreo\src\Header.php'); ?>
<?php include('C:\xampp\htdocs\webapps\Redesign\Oreo\src\Footer.php'); ?>

<?php echo pageHeader('Platform Tools'); ?>
<?php echo pageFooter(); ?>
```

When I try to run it it runs the header then closes the body and html tags and doesn't run the footer.

Any Suggestions and Thanks?

Comment: It's not possible. Can you paste the generated HTML?

Comment: Are you saying that when you have them both included, it's still outputting the closing `</body>` and `</html>` tags?

Comment: when you inspect the rendered HTML, you wont be seeing the footer end since js script tags are not written correctly they shud be ending with the `</script>` and not self closing tags

Comment: @Florent - it is possible, lots of modern browsers try and fix broken HTML and will append things like </body> and </html>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try changing your script tags from `<script src='/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js'/>` to `<script src='/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js'></script>`

Answer (score 0):

I checked out the code and it is rendering perfectly. <strike>Not a compulsion but</strike>  you should follow the way @Toby has asked for closing `script` tags.

I am sure its the issue with the way you are putting your script tags. Please correct them and everything will be fine.

**EDIT**

When you do the view source in the browser, the footer is seen in the HTML source as expected.
Only while rendering the footer is not shown, but once you correct the way script tags are added i.e. put proper end `</script>` browser will render it correctly

Comment: yes me too... but then never used script in that manner and hence doubted the same... also @Toby comment made me check with the fix and yeh it worked

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I do this all the time,

basically what I do is this

```
<?php include_once('Header.php'); ?>
Any Page content
<?php include_once('Footer.php'); ?>
```

The header includes

```
<html><head></head><body><div class="some-div">
```

And footer includes

```
</div></body></html>
```

This way you get constant header and footer, you don't need to make a separate function to close php document, it's unproductive.

**EDIT:**
And if you have index.php , for example, that has included files header.php and footer.php.

Comment: Yeah that's what i ended up doing. Thanks :)